# How should data be provided to a web server using a data warehouse?

Tags: sql, web, sftp, data-warehouse

We have data stored in a data warehouse as follows:

- Price
- Date
- Product Name (varchar(25))

We currently only have four products. That changes very infrequently (on average once every 10  years). Once every business day, four new data points are added representing the day's price for each product.

On the website, a user can request this information by entering a date range and selecting one or more products names. Analytics shows that the feature is not heavily used (about 10 users requests per week).

It was suggested that the data warehouse should daily push (SFTP) a CSV file containing all data (currently 6718 rows of this data and growing by four each day) to the web server. Then, the web server would read data from the file and display that data whenever a user made a request.

Usually, the push would only be once a day, but more than one push could be possible to communicate (infrequent) price corrections. Even in the price correction scenario, all data  would be delivered in the file. What are problems with this approach?

Would it be better to have the web server make a request to the data warehouse per user request? Or does this have issues such as a greater chance for network errors or performance issues?

Comment: I disagree with the suggestion of pushing a csv file.  Having a web page query a database is a fairly regular event.  In fact, as you get more data, it will be quicker than the csv file approach.

Comment: Why complicate things with a CSV web server push arrrangement. Is there a problem with the method you are using right now to deliver these figures to users?

Comment: Well, the issue that has been suggested is that a query to the database for every single HTTP page load will negatively effect performance on the data warehouse database. There is also a security concern which has not been fully explained to me yet.

Comment: I received clarification on the security concern. The concern is that by allowing the web server access to our data warehouse, sql injection attack or some other external attack through the website could compromise the data warehouse. Measures could be put in place to reduce the risk, but the easiest and safest approach has been deemed to  simply not allow any public facing system to directly access the data warehouse. In other words, the data warehouse can establish a communication with other servers, but no server can initiate a connection with the data warehouse. Does this seem reasonable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Would it be better to have the web server make a request to the data warehouse per user request?

Yes it would. You have very little data, so there is no need to try and 'cache' this in some way. (Apart from the fact that CSV might not be the best way to do this).
There is nothing stopping you from doing these requests from the webserver to the database server. With as little information as this you will not find performance an issue, but even if it would be when everything grows, there is a lot to be gained on the database-side (indexes etc) that will help you survive the next 100 years in this fashion.

The amount of requests from your users (also extremely small) does not need any special treatment, so again, direct query would be the best.

> Or does this have issues such as a greater chance for network errors or performance issues?

Well, it might, but that would not justify your CSV method. Examples and why you need not worry, could be

- the connection with the databaseserver is down.
  This is an issue for both methods, but with only one connection per day the change of a 1-in-10000 failures might seem to be better for once-a-day methods. But these issues should not come up very often, and if they do, you should be able to handle them. (retry request, give a message to user). This is what enourmous amounts of websites do, so trust me if I say that this will not be an issue. Also, think of what it would mean if your daily update failed? That would present a bigger problem!
- Performance issues
  as said, this is due to the amount of data and requests, not a problem. And even if it becomes one, this is a problem you should be able to catch at a different level. Use a caching system (non CSV) on the database server. Use a caching system on the webserver. Fix your indexes to stop performance from being a problem.

#### BUT:

It is far from strange to want your data-warehouse separated from your web system. If this is a requirement, and it surely could be, the best thing you can do is re-create your warehouse-database (the one I just defended as being good enough to query directly) on another machine. You might get good results by doing a master-slave system

- your datawarehouse is a master-database: it sends all changes to the slave but is inexcessible otherwise
- your 2nd database (on your webserver even) gets all updates from the master, and is read-only. you can only query it for data
- your webserver cannot connect to the datawarehouse, but can connect to your slave to read information. Even if there was an injection hack, it doesn't matter, as it is read-only.

Now you don't have a single moment where you update the queried database (the master-slave replication will keep it updated always), but no chance that the queries from the webserver put your warehouse in danger. profit!

Comment: +1 for the Master-Slave suggestion. I would do the same thing in OP's position if it was necessary, but with one input from the user things are pretty simple, and even with 100,000 rows OP shouldn't see performance issues and that's still 65 years out assuming no other changes.

Comment: agree. What I was trying to say (maybe needs clarification) that I would just query the database, unless the separation requirement was a strict requirement from somewhere else. If company policy is that no connection can be made to the warehouse server, then you might want to look at replication, but not otherwise :)

Comment: Thanks Nanne. I think the master-slave (MS) approach might work well with respect to the security concerns that I discovered after the OP. I noted these concerns in a comment below the OP. I recommended directly connecting (through JDBC) to the data warehouse database but was rebutted with performance and security concerns. I think others are now on board that performance is not an issue. But security is still deemed an issue since the data warehouse DB is in our data center and the web server is external (please see my comment above). MS could be a good way to alleviate the concern.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see how SQL injection could be a real concern. I assume you have some calendar type field that the user fills in to get data out. If this is the only form just ensure that the only field that is in it is a date then something like `DROP TABLE` isn't possible. As for getting access to the database, that is another issue. However, a separate file with just the connection function should do fine in most cases so that a user can't, say open your webpage in an HTML viewer and see your database connection string.

As for the CSV, I would have to say querying a database per user, especially if it's only used ~10 times weekly would be much more efficient than the CSV. I just equate the CSV as overkill because again you only have ~10 users attempting to get some information, to export an updated CSV every day would be too much for such little pay off.

EDIT:

Also if an attack is a big concern, which that really depends on the nature of the business, the data being stored, and the visitors you receive, you could always create a backup as another option. I don't really see a reason for this as your question is currently stated, but it is a possibility that even with the best security an attack could happen. That mainly just depends on if the attackers want the information you have.